# Find if a number is between two numbers that are in different columns, same row

Tags: excel

The numbers are days in a month ( 1-30 ) and I need to see as an example is the 5th (5) was included in those days, that where the 2nd and the 5th (one column has number 2 and the other has number 5).

At the same time I have to include if the day that started was the 29th and it ended the 1st of next month.

If A1 contains `5`, B1 contains `12` and C1 contains `24` I need to know if C1 is between A1 and B1, then I need to know if C2 is between A1 and B1, and then if C3 is between A1 and B1.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Perhaps an image would help

Comment: [Do **not** post screenshots of sample data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and (to @atclaus) [do **not** request screenshots of sample data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945) unless an image of sample data explains something that typed data cannot.

Comment: @Jeeped I could not understand his question as written so asked for more data. If you can make sense of it and help him as is more power to you.

Comment: Column A is the day of beginning of holidays, 5 (5th of february), and column B is the end of holidays, 10 (10th of february), and I need to check if the 10 (10th of february) is between those dates, I need to do it for a large data.

Comment: @atclaus: Yes, it needs more data. No, it does **not** need an image. You can't copy and paste an image of data into a spreadsheet to use for testing answers. Images should only be used to illustrate things that can't be explained any other way. The issue is not with needing more details - it's with your asking for an image of those details. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons **not** to post images.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The 5th of the month will always be between the 1st of the month and the end of the month (whether that end is the 28th, 29th, 30th, or 31st). I don't understand what *that where the 2nd and the 5th (one column has number 2 and the other has number 5* means, and I don't understand anything about what your second paragraph. You're going to need to [edit] to make it clear what you're asking. You can create a text table to display the data and use that for reference when explaining the problem.

Comment: You can also explain it using cell references: *A1 contains 5, B1 contains 7, and C1 contains 22. I need to see if <Acell> is between <thiscell> and <thisothercell>*. We'd like to help you, but you need to explain the problem clearly so we can do so.

Comment: Thank you very much, If A1 contains 5, B1 contains 12 and C1 contains 24 I need to know if C1is between A1 and B1 , then I need to know if C2 is Between A1 and B1, and then if C3 is between A1 and B1.

Answer (score 2):

> If A1 contains 5, B1 contains 12 and C1 contains 24 I need to know if C1is between A1 and B1 , then I need to know if C2 is Between A1 and B1, and then if C3 is between A1 and B1.

Try:

```
=AND(C1>A$1,C1<B$1)
```

in Row1, copied down to suit.

[image: SO39174461 example]